# Repeat the c program according to user

Tags: c

I want this program to repeat every time when users wants to continue.
I want user to choose "yes" to continue the program using other options but it's not executable. I used 'if else' statement for that but I am not getting any applicable or satisfying results. Can someone help me on this matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float a, b;
  int p;
  char q;
  printf("Enter the first number:");
  scanf("%f", &a);
  printf("Enter the second number:");
  scanf("%f", &b);
  printf("Choose the option:\n1.Sum\n \n2.Subtraction\n \n3.Multiplication\n \n4.Divison\n \nyour choice=");
  scanf("%d", &p);
  switch (p)
  {
  case 1:
    printf("The sum of above numbers is: %f", a + b);
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("The subtraction of above numbers is:%f", a - b);
    break;
  case 3:
    printf("The multiplication of above numbers is:%f", a * b);
    break;
  case 4:
    printf("The division of above numbers is:%f", a / b);
    break;
  }
  printf("\n\nDo u want to continue:(y for yes and n for no) :");
  scanf("%c", &q);
  if (q == 'y')
    return main();
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read your question again. There is not enough information. And please don't post links to pictures of text but post your text as properly formatted text into the question. You can [Edit] your question. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Post the code (indent by 4 spaces)

Comment: Hmm. You've been told not to post pictures of text....And I don't see any loop in the picture of your code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky oh sorry for the mistake on asking questions,, i have used if else statement to repeat the program once user has choosed yes but it's not happening

Comment: Don't be sorry but post your _actual_ code as text. There is no loop in your code, neither a for, nor a do, nor a while loop.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button to add the missing code into the question.

Comment: @Gerhardh i tried to but i am getting some problems while saving the question with my codes

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWmkO.png here is my code ss

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop for this. Explanations in the comments:

```
int main() {
  float a, b;
  int p;
  char q;

  do   // use a loop here
  {
    printf("Enter the first number:");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter the second number:");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Choose the option:\n1.Sum\n \n2.Subtraction\n \n3.Multiplication\n \n4.Divison\n \nyour choice=");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    switch (p)
    {
    case 1:
      printf("The sum of above numbers is: %f", a + b);
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("The subtraction of above numbers is:%f", a - b);
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("The multiplication of above numbers is:%f", a * b);
      break;
    case 4:
      printf("The division of above numbers is:%f", a / b);
      break;
    }
    printf("\n\nDo you want to continue: (y for yes and n for no) :");

    scanf(" %c", &q);  // use " %c"  instead of "%c", the white space
                       // will absorb any blank space (including newlines)

  } while (q == 'y');  // continue loop if user has entered 'y'
   
  return 0;
}
```